# How can I retrieve stuff from an useState declared variable in a component within another component scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, use-state, javascript-import

I want to get the investments variable within the scope of another component...

I have written the code down-bellow which is ok, but how can I get this const investment since I already exported the function InvestmentsList? How can that be done without resorting to useSelector() from react-redux?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Card,CardBody,CardHeader,CardTitle,Col,Row,Table} from 'reactstrap';
import moment from 'moment';

const InvestmentsList = () => {
  const [investment, setInvestment] = useState([]);
 async function fetchInvestments() {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/products');
    const investments = await response.json();
    // waits until the request completes...
    setInvestment(investments);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchInvestments();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>{/* ...Returns something */}</>)
export default InvestmentsList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access data of another component.

If two components are not to far from each other, you can also store the data in a parent component and provide "investment" as props to both components.

Also, Redux, React Context API or RecoilJS will allow you to store data of variable "investment" somewhere outside the component.

Comment: Can that be done usigng the rxjs library, @Promet99? How?
What I want to do is actually pass the income values of each investment to the corresponding investment page. i.e. it is another page

Comment: @lucasbbs Sorry, I havent used rxjs. But I think the principle is same. The data should be placed at the parent of components which will read/write those data. Maybe this [tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/rxjs-with-react-hooks-for-state-management/) will be of help